# i using a provider package to get product details from firebase then i facae error from firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety

i make this model to get product image,name,price from firebase but i'm facing exception error(FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.))

```
class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<ProductModel> pizzaProductList = [];
  ProductModel? productModel;

  fatchPizzaproductData() async {
    // List<ProductModel> newList = [];

    QuerySnapshot value =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("PizzaProducts").get();//here i face above error 

    pizzaProductList = value.docs.map((element) {
      return ProductModel(
        productImage: element.get("productImage"),
        productName: element.get("productName"),
        productPrice: element.get("productPrice"),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  List<ProductModel> get getPizzaproductDataList {
    return pizzaProductList;
  }
}
```

[image]

And here is the code where i get product details from firebase

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: productProvider!.getPizzaproductDataList.map(
            (pizzaproductDataList) {
              return Singleproduct(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => productOverVeiw(
                      productPrice: pizzaproductDataList.productPrice,
                      productImage: pizzaproductDataList.productImage,
                      productName: pizzaproductDataList.productName,
                    ),
                  ));
                },
                productImage: pizzaproductDataList.productImage,
                productName: pizzaproductDataList.productName,
                productPrice: pizzaproductDataList.productPrice,
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe due to your Firestore Database/Realtime Database not having permission. To fix this problem :

Go to Firestore Console Project and change Firestore Database rule into the following

From :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
  }
 }
}
```

Into :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: same still exist after changing

Comment: Does user authenticate? If not, if request.auth != null; is not gone work.